# jquery only the inputs that belong to the check all

Tags: jquery

How can i make this that the check all only focus the 4 inputs that belong to that check all? If you now click 2 (or 3) link all and you change one input all the inputs will change then. I only want that the inputs change that belong to that check all.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var s;

  $('.margin-checkall').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');
  });

  $('.css-margin').on('change', function() {
    s = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(s);
    if ($('.margin-checkall').hasClass('checked')) {

      $('.margin-checkall.checked').parent().parent().next('ul').find('li').each(function() {
        $(this).find('.css-margin').val(s);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  font: 12px/1.0em Arial;
}

.margin-checkall {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.margin-checkall:hover,
.margin-checkall.checked {
  color: #0085ba;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="css-layout-margin">
  <div class="caption">
    <div class="link">
      <span class="margin-checkall">Link all values.</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <label>Top</label>
      <input type="text" class="css-margin" value="" tabindex="1">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Right</label>
      <input type="text" class="css-margin" value="" tabindex="2">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Bottom</label>
      <input type="text" class="css-margin" value="" tabindex="3">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Left</label>
      <input type="text" class="css-margin" value="" tabindex="4">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="css-layout-margin">
  <div class="caption">
    <div class="link">
      <span class="margin-checkall">Link all values.</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <label>Top</label>
      <input type="text" class="css-margin" value="" tabindex="1">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Right</label>
      <input type="text" class="css-margin" value="" tabindex="2">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Bottom</label>
      <input type="text" class="css-margin" value="" tabindex="3">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Left</label>
      <input type="text" class="css-margin" value="" tabindex="4">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="css-layout-margin">
  <div class="caption">
    <div class="link">
      <span class="margin-checkall">Link all values.</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <label>Top</label>
      <input type="text" class="css-margin" value="" tabindex="1">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Right</label>
      <input type="text" class="css-margin" value="" tabindex="2">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Bottom</label>
      <input type="text" class="css-margin" value="" tabindex="3">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Left</label>
      <input type="text" class="css-margin" value="" tabindex="4">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `$('.margin-checkall')`. This gets all elements with this class, whereas you only want the one that is right before your input elements in the code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.margin-checkall').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');
  });

  $('.css-margin').on('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $container = $this.closest('.css-layout-margin');
    if ($container.find('.margin-checkall').hasClass('checked')) {
      $container.find('.css-margin').val($this.val());
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with one more solution:- https://jsfiddle.net/rjjuw03o/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 var s;

  $('.margin-checkall').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');
  });

  $('.css-margin').on('change', function() {
    s = $(this).val();
  $(this).val(s);
    var test = $(this).closest('.css-layout-margin').find('.margin-checkall');
    if ($(test).hasClass('checked')) {

      $(test).parent().parent().next('ul').find('li').each(function() {
        $(this).find('.css-margin').val(s);
      });
    }
  });

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  font: 12px/1.0em Arial;
}

.margin-checkall {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.margin-checkall:hover,
.margin-checkall.checked {
  color: #0085ba;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="css-layout-margin">
  <div class="caption">
    <div class="link">
      <span class="margin-checkall">Link all values.</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <label>Top</label>
      <input type="text" class="css-margin" value="" tabindex="1">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Right</label>
      <input type="text" class="css-margin" value="" tabindex="2">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Bottom</label>
      <input type="text" class="css-margin" value="" tabindex="3">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Left</label>
      <input type="text" class="css-margin" value="" tabindex="4">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="css-layout-margin">
  <div class="caption">
    <div class="link">
      <span class="margin-checkall">Link all values.</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <label>Top</label>
      <input type="text" class="css-margin" value="" tabindex="1">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Right</label>
      <input type="text" class="css-margin" value="" tabindex="2">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Bottom</label>
      <input type="text" class="css-margin" value="" tabindex="3">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Left</label>
      <input type="text" class="css-margin" value="" tabindex="4">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="css-layout-margin">
  <div class="caption">
    <div class="link">
      <span class="margin-checkall">Link all values.</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <label>Top</label>
      <input type="text" class="css-margin" value="" tabindex="1">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Right</label>
      <input type="text" class="css-margin" value="" tabindex="2">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Bottom</label>
      <input type="text" class="css-margin" value="" tabindex="3">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Left</label>
      <input type="text" class="css-margin" value="" tabindex="4">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Instead of looping through all the **.margin-checkall**, just loop through the focused input div.